# Drawing two borders intertwined

Tags: html, css

I want to draw this:

[image]

So I wrote this code:

HTML:

```html
<div class="outer_border_cp">
    <div class="inside_border_cp"><p>تعديل معلومات المستخدم</p></div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.outer_border_cp {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-left: -10px;
}
.inside_border_cp {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: static;
}
```

But I got this result:

[image]

How can I complete this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your CSS to this, and it works:

```
.outer_border_cp {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.inside_border_cp {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 10px -10px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: static;
}
```

You can see it on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cgvlD

Answer (score 1):

Try using `margin-left:-10px` rather than `padding-left:-10px`. You cannot have negative padding values in CSS.